# how to verify a class using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to be able to verify (or assert) that a class ("box") is present.

Can I do this with Selenium IDE?

Here's an example of html using class "box"

```
 ...
 <div class="box documentText">
    ...
 </div>
 ...
```

How can I verify that a page contains this class "box"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Selenium IDE to new window
2. Load the page you want to test (i.e. usual setup :) )
3. **Right click** the element you want to check if its present on the page
4. Select *Show all available commands*
5. Select command "verifyElementPresent"
6. You are done! ;)

Comment: That's it. Very easy. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

1. Enter URl in the FF browser and open the website
2. Open Selenium IDE In FF browser
3. Right click the element you want to check if its present on the page
4. Hover over all available commands
5. Select command "verifyElementPresent" or Assertelementpresent

Check image [image: here]

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter URl in the FF browser and open the website
2. Open Selenium IDE In FF browser
3. Right click the element you want to check if its present on the page
4. Hover over all available commands
5. Select command "verifyElementPresent" or `Assertelementpresent`
6. You are done!

Answer (score 1):

Use assertElementPresent command as shown below.

```
 Command: assertElementPresent
 Target: class=box
```